# Javascript capitilizing first letter in each word in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a function that should capitalize every first letter in each word in a string, but somehow it delivers incorrect result, any idea why? I need to fix it a bit.

So the input: hello dolly  output: Hello Dolly.

Spaces are correctly counted but the capitalization is incorrect.

```js
function letterCapitalize(str) {
  str = str.replace(str.charAt(0), str.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  let spaces = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === ' ') spaces.push(i);
  }
  for (let space of spaces) {
    str = str.replace(str.charAt(space + 1), str.charAt(space + 1).toUpperCase());
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(letterCapitalize("hello there, how are you?"));
```

Comment: I am aware that replace replaces just the first occurance, but how should I make work it properly?

Comment: What's the difference between your function and `.toUpperCase()`?

Comment: `const letterCapitalize = x => x.toUpperCase();`

Comment: `const letterCapitalize = x => x.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, l => l.toUpperCase())`

Comment: @Tibike no need of A-Z inside character class, as OP is trying to change to uppercase, so /[a-z]/ will be enough

Comment: @CodeManiac: Good thinking! :-)

Comment: @ASDFGerte toUpperCase converts all to uppercase, I need just the first letter so from hi dolly => Hi Dolly

Comment: "should capitalize every letter in string" - from your own question.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I edited my question, cuz I noticed the word first somehow got out

Comment: CSS: `.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;   
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Option One

function capitalize1( str ) {
  let result = str[ 0 ].toUpperCase();

  for ( let i = 1; i < str.length; i++ ) {
    if ( str[ i - 1 ] === ' ' ) {
      result += str[ i ].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result += str[ i ];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Option Two

function capitalize2(str) {
  const words = [];

  for (let word of str.split(' ')) {
    words.push(word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
  }

  return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalize1('hello there, how are you?'))
console.log(capitalize2('hello there, how are you?'))
```

Comment: YEY! thats it man, thats exactly what I needed... idk why I wanted to use replace for all cost, this is more simple. Thanks @mplungjan

Comment: and also thank you @SakoBu

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.toUpperCase()` or if you require more specific logic you could use `string.replace()` with some regular expression

```js
const letterCapitalize = x => x.toUpperCase();

const letterCapitalizeWithRegex = x => x.replace(/[a-z]/g, l => l.toUpperCase());

console.log("my string".toUpperCase());

console.log(letterCapitalize("my string"));

console.log(letterCapitalizeWithRegex("my string"));
```

Comment: The question was adjusted, I need just every first letter of the string, not all characters